# Is there any difference between "see what happens" and "see what's going to happen"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *see what happens* and *see what's going to happen*? For example:

> I can't say which boxer and how will win. Let's just wait and **see what happens**.
>
> I can't say which boxer and how will win. Let's just wait and **see what's going to happen**.

Comment: No meaningful difference. Unrelatedly, the construction "which boxer and how will win" is technically acceptable but hard to make sense of. "Which boxer will win and how" would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

**See what happens** is a phrase that has more emphasis on the outcome, whereas **See what's going on** can mean the same, but more emphasis on **seeing what's happening in the process that's bringing about the outcome**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I specifically asked about the difference between "see what happens" and "see what is going to HAPPEN'